# React: Nested arrow function is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

Well. I broke things again.

So the idea here is I'm trying to create an arrow function to display some data, and in the process I'm aiming to create a SECOND arrow function within the first to map out some of the data into a list but things have broken.

According to my browser, `serverInfoTabList` is not defined.

```
const VarInfo = (props) =>  {

    serverInfoTabList = (var) => {
        if (var != undefined){
            return //mappingstuff {
                //more var stuff
                return (
                    <li 
                        {var}
                    </li>
                );
            });
        }
    }

    return (
        props.var!= undefined ? 
        <div className={props.var}>
            <h1>{props.var.map}</h1>
            {/* <img src={props.var.image}/> */}
            <div>
                <ul>  
                    {this.serverInfoTabList(props.var)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        : 
        null
    );
}
```

Comment: You have `serverInfoTabList` once and `this.serverInfoTabList` the second time. Don't you need only one or the other? Because the two do *not* refer to the same thing.

Comment: Why `this.`? What did you expect `this` to be in this case?

Comment: Please show the exact error message and indicate what line causes the error.

Comment: I thought that by using ```this``` as the pretext in ```{this.serverInfoTabList(props.var)}```, that I would be referencing the function defined above... but now I am told they are not the same? What would I need to do in order to correct this err?

@Code-Apprentice Line 7:5:    'serverInfoTabList' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @ThirdGhostHand `this` is often called the "context". It isn't a reference to the function itself. Even if it were, `serverInfoTabList` is a local variable inside your function and not an attribute of the function.

Comment: Oh.. that's metal..

Comment: This question was answered in the following post;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628720/react-rendering-a-method-defined-inside-arrow-function

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
this.serverInfoTabList(props.var)
```

to

```
serverInfoTabList(props.var)
```

Since you define a functional component, you don't need to use `this` in this particular context. If you defined your component as a class, then you would need to use `this`.

Note: Don't use `var` as a variable name since this is a reserved word in JavaScript.

Comment: Well now both of them are undefined.. 

"
  Line 7:5:    'serverInfoTabList' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 34:22:  'serverInfoTabList' is not defined  no-undef
"

Comment: @ThirdGhostHand Please post a new question that shows your modified code and indicates what lines cause the errors.

Comment: `var` isn't a variable, it's a property of an object. I'm not actually sure whether this is OK or not.

Comment: @DavidKnipe In `props.var`, you are correct. The OP also declares `(var) => {}` which seems problematic to me. Both cases might actual work, but should be avoided. Besides `var` as a variable name gives absolutely no information about what the variable represents.