# React: Rendering a method defined inside arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, arrow-functions

Hello friends! I hope you are well.

I've got an arrow function called `WorldInfo` and its parent component is passing down an object in props that for the sake of this example, I'm just calling `object`. Now In `WorldInfo` I also want to parse and list the `items` in `object`, so I've created the method `serverInfoTabList` to take `object` and shove it through `.map`. My problem is when compiled, my browser does not recognize `serverInfoTabList` either when it's defined nor called in `WorldInfo`'s own return function.

Here is the error and the code itself.

```
 Line 7:5:    'serverInfoTabList' is not defined  no-undef
 Line 34:22:  'serverInfoTabList' is not defined  no-undef
```

```
const WorldInfo = (props) =>  {

    serverInfoTabList = (object) => {
        if (object != undefined){
            return object.item.map((item) => {
                const time = Math.trunc(item.time/60)
                return (
                    <li key={item._id}>{item.name}
                        <br/>
                        Minutes Online: {time}
                    </li>
                );
            });
        }
    }

    return (
        props.object!= undefined ? 
        <div className={props.className}>
            <h1>{props.world.map}</h1>
            {/* <img src={props.object.image}/> */}
            <div>
                <ul>  
                    {serverInfoTabList(props.object)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        : 
        null
    );
}
```

Thanks for your time friendos!

Comment: Try declaring it with the ```const``` keyword.  Also note that ```map``` will only work on an array, not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `const` declaration

```
const serverInfoTabList = (object) => {
    /* ... */
}
```

The other problem is that you're accessing properties which doesn't exist `props.world` for instance. Also you're mapping through an undefined property `props.object.item`. I've corrected your sandbox

```
const WorldInfo = props => {
  const serverInfoTabList = object => {
    return Object.keys(object).map(key => {
      const item = object[key];
      const time = Math.trunc(item.time / 60);
      return (
        <li key={item._id}>
          {item.name}
          <br />
          Minutes Online: {time}
        </li>
      );
    });
  };

  return props.object ? (
    <div className={props.className}>
      <h1>{props.world.map}</h1>
      {/* <img src={props.object.image}/> */}
      <div>
        <ul>{serverInfoTabList(props.object)}</ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : null;
};

class Todo extends Component {
  render() {
    const object = { item1: { _id: 1, time: 1 }, Item2: { _id: 2, time: 2 } };
    return (
      <div>
        <WorldInfo object={object} world={{ map: "foo" }} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit React example]

Comment: Well. This does change the error. Now it's saying:

"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.serverInfoTabList is not a function"

Comment: Are you calling `serverInfoTabList` from `this`?

Comment: You mean like this? 
```{this.serverInfoTabList(props.world)}``` Either way, the same error is returned.

Comment: Yeah. But you shouldn't. `this` is for class based components. Can you post a sandbox?

Comment: Uhm. Yeah. That's a good idea. Give me a second, I've never done it before.

Comment: Alright.... I think I've replicated the data relevant to the scenario. Obviously it doesn't work... cuz there's a bug.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-9ovbr?fontsize=14

Comment: *facepalm*
I had another whole error stopping this sucker from getting rendered...
But this answer solves that problem too. So thank you! You're a god.